# Difficulty executing SQL Server stored procedure programmatically using Python and ODBC

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

I have an Amazon EC2 instance hosting a Microsoft SQL Server, and I'm attempting to execute a stored procedure programmatically using Python and ODBC. While I can successfully execute the stored procedure through SQL Server Management Studio, I encounter an issue when attempting to execute it using Python and ODBC.

```
    connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    print("Connected to DB")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"EXEC <schema>.<procedure-name>")

    cursor.fetchall()
```

I tried this, but it is returning None.

### Additional Things:

1. I have confirmed that the connection string (conn_str) is correct.
2. The stored procedure executes successfully in SQL Server Management Studio.
3. I have checked the permissions for the stored procedure and verified that the user has the        necessary permissions to execute it.
4. I'm using Python and pyodbc

Comment: add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of the procedure

Comment: Whaty error are you getting?  Try stepping through to see if you get an error or put a catch error block around it (however you would do that in python)